# How do I save a Google web cache version of page?

Tags: archive.org, cached-webpages

When an article or comments are deleted, it can be useful to look at the Google web cache to retrieve it. However, my understanding is that the Google web cache might likely change in the future. I can use The Wayback Machine to save a page as it currently is - but I can't save the web cache view, due to robots.txt.

Is there a way to save, on The Wayback Machine or any other reputable online archive tool, the Google web cache as it currently is?

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason, I've gotten mixed results with [Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/). In the past, I thought I was able to save cached pages. Today it said that the site was overloaded and to try again in 600 minutes.

On the other hand, [Archive.today](https://archive.ph/) works reliably for cached pages. For example, https://archive.ph/x65wT is the archived version of the cache of [SQL sanitizing in code with no user input](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/444353/sql-sanitizing-in-code-with-no-user-input).

Note: It's possible that some pages won't show up in Google's cache at all. Nothing can be done about that except maybe saving the page directly.